# Java regular expression is validating the date in ddMMMyyy but not validating yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: java, date, match, group

I want to validate different kinds of strings which are of different format like
`10JUN2022`, `2Mx1D`, `4M`, `1D`, `TEN`, `ONE|TEN` etc.. and I have written regular expression for that `'''^([0-9A-WYZa-wyz ]+)([xX|]([0-9A-WYZa-wyz ]+))?$'''` and it's working fine but I also need to validate one more  string `2022-06-10`, but the expression is failing.

Comment: Regex can help you with regular expressions, but when the expressions become a lot and very different each other (like the ones you have here), it soon becomes hard to follow your regular expression. I'd rather suggest you hold a collection of `SimpleDateFormatter`s, each with a different date pattern, and you loop through it when validating a date. It may be less efficient but it's definitely way more flexible and especially more understandable.

Comment: By the way, the [*ISO 8601*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines sensible unambiguous date-time formats. I suggest educating the publisher of your data about adopting ISO 8601 to replace this hodgepodge of formats. For example a span of two months and a day would be `P2M1DT`. The tenth of June this year would be `2022-06-10`.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Good suggestion, except that `SimpleDateFormat` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes, specifically `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: `^(([0-9A-WYZa-wyz ]+)([xX|]([0-9A-WYZa-wyz ]+))?)|(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$`?

Comment: I would recommend also basing the validation on the meaning of those strings since it will help the reader of your code understand. I take `2Mx1D` to be 2 months 1 day? What is `TEN`? Nothing to do with date and time? What is `ONE|TEN`?

Comment: they are just different string I am validating with the same regex

Comment: @BasilBourque you're right, I always confuse the new one with the old one (until when I import it and realize it's the other one I wanted to import)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to regex, don't try to get overly clever. Just solve the basic problem.  If that takes multiple regex patterns, so be it.  It's much easier to maintain and read.

I would use this for the first regex: `[0-3]?\d\w{3}(1|2)\d{3}`
and this for the second regex: `(1|2)\d{3}(-\d{2}){2}`
or combine them if you must: `([0-3]?\d\w{3}(1|2)\d{3})|((1|2)\d{3}(-\d{2}){2})`